# Checking User Input in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that asks for the user's input then returns the information with a statement. This code below just returns a blank statement. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am using python idle.

```
gnc = input ("Enter gnc here: ")
if input == "masculine singular nominative":
    print ("qui")
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It's returning a blank statement because that's what you told it to do.

Comment: you store your input in `gnc` but then try to compare `input` against a string with whitespace

Comment: I just left the blanks in there to show that's where the user input would go.

Comment: read what the sheep said - that's your problem

Comment: What do you want to input, and what should be the output?

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison of `gnc` will not be true unless the user enters two spaces when prompted. Try the following, and the gnc will be available in the variable `gnc`.

```
gnc = input ("Enter gnc here: ")
if not gnc:
    print ("gnc is empty")
print("The value of gnc is: {}".format(gnc))
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I missed that when I copied the original code. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to print only if it's a valid input (not null)

You have to check if the input value is not empty or just spaces. For that you need to trim the extra spaces in your input and if the condition satisfies you need to print!

```
gnc = input("Enter gnc here: ")
if str(gnc).strip(): 
    print("Value of gnc is %s", str(gnc))
else: 
    print("gnc is empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

easier:

```
gnc = raw_input("Enter gnc here: ")
if not gnc:
    print ("Empty")
print gnc
```